# how to run javascript function 'live' without refresh?

Tags: javascript, html, average, live

im trying to make a average grade calculator, now thats is going fine but now i want to calculate the average immediately when a number gets inputted in one of the fields. I've been trying this with "on(), live(), onkeyup()" but can't get it to work.

The result of the average now displays beneath the inputfields 'onclick' on the button. I want the average displayed there but then as soon as you input numbers in one of the fields it should show there as it now does after the onclick.

What i've tryed with the 'on(), live(), onkeyup()' is to connect them to the input fields and connect them to the calculator() function.

Is there a easy way to do this or a other certain way?
greetings.

```js
function calculator()  {    
  var weight = 0;
  var mark = 0;
  var weights = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=weight-]');
  var grades = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=mark-]');
  var trs = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  var tBody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
  var totalWeight = 0;
  var totalGrade = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {
    totalWeight += +weights[i].value;
    
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
    totalGrade += +grades[i].value;
  }


  var finalGrade=totalGrade/totalWeight;
  var display = document.getElementById('output-div');
  var newTr = document.createElement('TR');
  newTr.innerHTML = `<td><input id="weight-${trs.length + 1}" type="text" size=2 value=""></td><td><input id="mark-${trs.length + 1}" type="text" size=2 value=""></td>`;
  tBody.appendChild(newTr);
  display.innerHTML='Je gemiddelde is: ' +finalGrade.toFixed(2);
}
```

```css
html {
  background-color: ;
}


header {
  background-color: ; 
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
 
table {
  margin: auto;
}

tr {
  background-color: ;
}

td {
  background-color: ;
}

#table-title {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

input {
  text-align: center;
}

[id^="mark"] {
  width: 100px;
}

[id^="weight"] {
  width: 100px;
}




#calc-btn-div {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  margin: auto;
}

#calc-btn {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#calc-btn:hover {
  border-color: black;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
}

/* #add-input-div {
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#add-input-btn {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 20px; 
}

#add-input-btn:hover {
  border-color: black;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
} */

  #output-div { 
  background-color: ;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
} 











/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<header>
  <h2>Gemiddelde cijfer</h2>
  <h3>Voer hieronder je cijfers in</h3>
</header>
  
<body>
  <table id="table">
    
    <tr id="table-title">
      <td>Weging</td>
      <td>Cijfer</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><input id="weight-1" type="text" size=2 value=""></td>
      <td><input id="mark-1" type="text" size=2 value=""></td>
    </tr>
    
  </table>
  <div id="calc-btn-div">
    <input id="calc-btn" type="button" value="Berekenen je gemiddelde" onclick="calculator()">
  </div>
  
<!--   <div id="add-input-div">
    <input id="add-input-btn" type="button" value="Voeg cijfer toe" onclick="addInput()">
  </div> -->

  <div id="output-div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "on(), live(), onkeyup()" are not in your example, and they're all jQuery methods which is not used in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Using vanilla JavaScript I would attach an eventListener to the inputfields like this

```
document.getElementById('weight-1').addEventListener('change',function(){
    calculator();
});

document.getElementById('mark-1').addEventListener('change',function(){
    calculator();
});
```

These addEventListener functions adds listeners to the "input" field's predefined 'change'-events, and fires the calculator(); function from your code.

Seeing that you are using some sort of dynamic generation of the inputfields, you could add the listeners to your inputfields using the same querySelector that you use to target them during calculation. It would mean replacing `getElementById('weight-1')` in my example above with `querySelectorAll('[id^=weight-]')` for the weight-fields.

Also, doing work with values, IO, and calculation between html and JavaScript, I would suggest using a library like jQuery. jQuery simplifies these processes a lot.
This is the documentation for the jQuery alternative onClick function:
https://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score -1):

I think you could do that with an angularJS module. Take a look at this tutorial : https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_modules.asp 
maybe it will help.

Comment: this has nothing to do with Angular? why suggest an angular module?

Comment: Because with angular you can bind an expression directly to an HTML attribute and it could be quite appropriate here. I don't think it's essential  to use angular in this case but I thought it might offer a quick and easy solution, that's why I suggested that...